# Get number of days between 2 dates in the same column in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Goal: Identify records where the difference in their effective date between 2 transactions is greater than 365 days.

Example of table:

```
account#    Effective_Date
1234        01/01/2020
1234        02/01/2020
1234        03/01/2020
1234        04/01/2021
```

I would like to create a table to look like this

```
account     Effective_Date  Effective_Date_1   Calculate_Days
1234        01/01/2020                         0  
1234        02/01/2020      01/01/2020         31
1234        03/01/2020      02/01/2020         29
1234        04/01/2021      03/01/2020         395
```

goal 1: duplicate effective date in another column "effective_date_1"
goal 2: offset "effective_date_1" by 1 row

is this possible in SQL?

Comment: Yes it is. What DBMS are you using? This is very simple in modern DBMS that feature the `LAG` function.

Comment: Use the `LAG()` function.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()`.  In SQL Server, this looks like:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(day, lag(effective_date), effective_date) as num_days
from t;
```

Note:  This returns `NULL` for the first row.  If you really want `0`, then the 3-argument form is handy:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(day, lag(effective_date, 1, effective_date), effective_date) as num_days
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

lag statement must use with over() and order by in it.

```
select t.*
    ,lag(Effective_Date) over(order by Effective_Date)
    ,datediff(day, lag(Effective_Date) over(order by Effective_Date) , Effective_Date)
from (
    select  1234  as account#      ,'01/01/2020' as Effective_Date
    union
    select  1234  as account#      ,'02/01/2020' as Effective_Date
    union
    select  1234  as account#      ,'03/01/2020' as Effective_Date
    union
    select  1234  as account#      ,'04/01/2021' as Effective_Date
) t
```